# TypeScript: How to type "if a this key is present, this other key must be too" without explicitly copying everything over

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, union-types, intersection-types

I have a custom type like this (this code doesn't work):

```
type MyType =
  | {
      foo: string;
    }
  | {
      foo: string;
      barPre: string;
      barPost: string;
    }
  | {
      foo: string;
      quxPre: string;
      quxPost: string;
    }
  | {
      foo: string;
      barPre: string;
      barPost: string;
      quxPre: string;
      quxPost: string;
    };
```

I basically want the following objects to be valid `MyType`s:

```
const myThing1: MyType = { foo: 'foo' };
const myThing2: MyType = { foo: 'foo', barPre: 'barPre', barPost: 'barPost' };
const myThing3: MyType = { foo: 'foo', quxPre: 'quxPre', quxPost: 'quxPost' };
const myThing4: MyType = {
  foo: 'foo',
  barPre: 'barPre',
  barPost: 'barPost',
  quxPre: 'quxPre',
  quxPost: 'quxPost',
};
```

And the following objects should be invalid `MyType`s:

```
const myThing5: MyType = {}; // missing 'foo'
const myThing6: MyType = { barPre: 'barPre', barPost: 'barPost' }; // missing 'foo'
const myThing7: MyType = { foo: 'foo', barPre: 'barPre' }; // if `barPre` exists, `barPost` must, too.
const myThing8: MyType = { barPre: 'barPre', barPost: 'barPost', quxPre: 'quxPre', quxPost: 'quxPost' }
```

I got the correct type hints, by typing it like this:

```
type MyType = {
  foo: string;
} & ({
  barPre?: undefined;
  barPost?: undefined;
} | {
  barPre: string;
  barPost: string;
}) & ({
  quxPre?: undefined;
  quxPost?: undefined;
} | {
  quxPre: string;
  quxPost: string;
});
```

But this seems very tedious. Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the weird excess property checking Typescript does for unions. See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36945

There is a strict union type you can define that works at least in your case. I've not tried this in earnest but you can read about it [here](https://digital.interhyp.de/2022/02/17/strict-unions-in-typescript-a-practical-approach/).

Define a StrictUnion type as:

```
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> = T extends T ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, undefined>> : never
type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>
```

and then use that in your union

`type MyType = StrictUnion<A | B | C | D>`

It's then reporting errors myThing5, 6, 7 and 8 as you'd expect.